# How to determine if a certain number of "$1:1.125$" rectangles can tile a "$1:1.6$" rectangle

Tags: geometry

Say I have two rectangular ratios. One rectangle's height is one and an eighth times its width, and another rectangle's height is one and three fifths times its width. I wish to find whether or not certain numbers of rectangles of the first ratio can tile a single rectangle of the second ratio from edge to edge.

It would be really neat if there were a way to do this using a linear algebra operation on four vector lengths.

Comment: Are the rectangle ratios $9\times 8$ and $8\times 5$? Obviously the area of the larger rectangle will have to be a multiple of the area of the smaller rectangle and each of the sides of the larger will have to be achievable as a linear combination of the sides of the smaller.

Comment: Yes. The h:w ratios are 1.125:1 for the tiling rectangle and 1.6:1 for the tiled one.

Comment: Are we allowed to rotate the smaller rectangle (by multiples of 90°)? Or do all tiles have to be in the same direction?

Comment: I would like to see a solution that used rotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we define $r_{1}$ as the rectangle with height $h_{r_{1}}=\frac{9w_{r_{1}}}{8}$ and width $w_{r_{1}}$ and $r_{2}$ as the rectancle with height $h_{r_{2}}=\frac{8w_{r_{2}}}{5}$ and width $w_{r_{1}}$, then $A_{r_{1}} = \frac{9 w_{r_1}^2}{8}$ and $A_{r_{2}}=\frac{8 w_{r_2}^2}{5}$

The only way $r_{1}$ can tile $r_{2}$ without any remainder is if $A_{r_{2}} > A_{r_{1}} \implies A_{r_{2}} = A_{r_{1}}x$

We can solve the equation for $x$ and we get $x = \frac{64 w_{r_2}^2}{45 w_{r_1}^2}$

Furthermore, if $w_{r_{1}} > 0 \land w_{r_{2}}>0$, then $w_{r_1}>0\land w_{r_2}>\frac{3}{8} \sqrt{5} \sqrt{w_{r_1}^2}$

The answer really depends on the width of the rectangles: $r_1$ can tile $r_2$ $x$ times